# Most semantically correct and type-safe construction from serialized byte array? (c++11)

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, semantics, type-safety

Consider the following c++11 class which represents an IPv4 header structure that should be constructable from a byte array regardless of byte ordering.

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

namespace Net {
  using addr_t = ::in_addr_t;
  #pragma pack(push, 1)
  struct ip_header_t {
    uint8_t  ver_ihl;
    uint8_t  tos;
    uint16_t total_length;
    uint16_t id;
    uint16_t flags_fo;
    uint8_t  ttl;
    uint8_t  protocol;
    uint16_t checksum;
    addr_t   src_addr;
    addr_t   dst_addr;

    ip_header_t( const uint8_t* bytes, const bool ntoh = false ) {
      auto o = (ip_header_t&)*bytes;
      ver_ihl      = o.ver_ihl;
      tos          = o.tos;
      ttl          = o.ttl;
      protocol     = o.protocol;
      total_length = ntoh? ntohs(o.total_length) : o.total_length;
      id           = ntoh? ntohs(o.id) : o.id;
      flags_fo     = ntoh? ntohs(o.flags_fo) : o.flags_fo;
      checksum     = ntoh? ntohs(o.checksum) : o.checksum;
      src_addr     = ntoh? ntohl(o.src_addr) : o.src_addr;
      dst_addr     = ntoh? ntohl(o.dst_addr) : o.dst_addr;
    };
  };
  #pragma pack(pop)
}
```

I'm concerned that accepting a byte array may not be the safest or most *semantically correct* way to do this.  Casting the array as the structure itself seems like a very C-ish method that lacks type safety (not to mention bounds checking).  Would it be better to require the caller to worry about that and require a const reference to an instance?

Comment: I think this method is generally fine...whenever you deal with byte arrays directly, you are going to get "C-ish" implementations. One thing to make sure is that the struct is built in a packed manner: there is no standard for this (unfortunately), but here are the [gcc struct packing pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html). You can always hide the byte array constructor from the end user.

Comment: A const reference to an instance *of what*? If you're proposing that the caller should be responsible for providing the header structure, then what's the point of your code at all?

Comment: a const reference to an instance of the structure itself--like a copy constructor, but with the added bool parameter.  The purpose of the code would be to allow conversions from network byte-order.

Comment: Another benefit that occurs to me now is that I could also use an initialization list for those members that don't require translation if the parameter were such a const reference.

Comment: @MSD: you're right, I neglected to specify the packing alignment.  I updated the question example to reflect proper alignment.

Answer (score 0):

Casting byte array to this class is definitely not the right thing to do - as you have mentioned byte order might be different on different systems (that's why there is an `ntohs` in the constructor).

Where you put your class depends entirely on roles and responsibilities of your entities. Without seeing the design there is no way to tell.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean.  On a system where network byte order is the same as host byte order, ntohX() will not re-order any bytes.

Answer (score 0):

A type to represent raw binary data, with a presumed layout of some kind:

```
template<typename T, size_t order>
struct serial_tag {};
```

Introducing some names representing the expected type and layout of data on disk:

```
typedef serial_tag<uint8_t , 0> ver_ihl_ser;
typedef serial_tag<uint8_t , 1> tos_ser;
typedef serial_tag<uint16_t, 2> total_length_ser;
    ...
typedef serial_tag<addr_t  , 9> dst_addr_ser;
```

A pack of serial_tags, which can then be manipulated by other code:

```
template<typename... tags>
struct serial_pack {};
```

Write code that takes a serial_pack, and ensures every ordinal is in use with no gaps.

Write code that takes a deserialization iterator and a serial_tag, and advances that deserialization iterator while generating the data from the serial_tag.  This should handle endianness

The goal is to describe the raw data layout of the data in a way ameniable to metaprogramming, then load the data into a C++ struct using this layout information.

This is a streaming read operation, where the deserialization iterator (or range) knows if it has a limit on how big it is, and knows if you are properly reading elements in order (at least in debug).

I do not know if this is worth it, but it does address your concerns.

A downside to this approach is that it violates DRY, in that the in-memory layout could in theory be used as a way to describe the raw-byte layout post-serialization.  Instead, we have to maintain a completely different set of data to represent that.  As a plus side, this means that our in-C++ layout doesn't have to exactly copy the binary layout.

Comment: That does serve the interest of type safety and also provides the semantic benefit of explicitly declaring the serialized order.  What about an input stream for which operator>> is overloaded such that it can re-order multi-byte types?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the best solution would be to provide a copy constructor that could handle byte-order translation and rely on the caller to make the cast.

Like so:

```
/* copy constructor: */
ip_header_t( const ip_header_t& src, const bool ntoh = false )
  : ver_ihl(src.ver_ihl),
    tos(src.tos),
    ttl(src.ttl),
    protocol(src.protocol) {
  total_length = ntoh? ntohs(src.total_length) : src.total_length;
  id           = ntoh? ntohs(src.id)           : src.id;
  flags_fo     = ntoh? ntohs(src.flags_fo)     : src.flags_fo;
  checksum     = ntoh? ntohs(src.checksum)     : src.checksum;
  src_addr     = ntoh? ntohl(src.src_addr)     : src.src_addr;
  dst_addr     = ntoh? ntohl(src.dst_addr)     : src.dst_addr;
};

/* client code using byte array in network-order */
auto ip_header = Net::ip_header_t((Net::ip_header_t&)*(byte_array), true);
```

I'm not 100% certain that I like this solution the best, either.  It may yet be better to make a non-member function that does this considering that the byte-order swapping is not strictly relevant to the object's construction.  It's also maybe not the rightful responsibility of the class to concern itself with field alignment and ordering.